# How to make Intellij (19.3) to perform absolute auto imports for python?

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea

It seems the paths are relative to the root package. Should I define the project folder as the source root of the Intellij module, instead of the package folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S.
Click on Proj. Settings / Modules
Click on  / Sources tab
Set as Source only the project root folder and mark as Excluded all folders that should not be considered as source or indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Setting the project folder as the root will change the paths to be relative to that folder